# create domain name like co.cc

Tags: dns

three month ago I have site registered at co.cc. I want to know how they create domain name like ".cc" not ".com". I never seen site like this and .cc is not standard domain. So my question is how they create their own domain name? can I create my own domain like www.abc.jagdish insteda of www.abc.com?

Comment: What do you mean .cc is not standard domain? Of course it is. And this has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: `can I create my own domain like www.abc.jagdish insteda of www.abc.com?` nope. You'd need to be a huge entity with lots of money to even have a chance of getting your own tld

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cc.

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer. It is standard domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how they create domain name like ".cc"

That is a (completely standard) [country code top level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain), specifically the one for the [Cocos (Keeling) Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cc). They got the domain by being the official registrar for that country or by buying it from them.

To create your own CCTLD you would first have to found a country. That seems like an excessive expense for the purposes of having a custom TLD.

Comment: His question is to create his own extension like `www.abc.jagdish`

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer. It is standard domain

Answer (score 1):

You can't create your own domain. Wait it is possible to register your own extension but it will cost roughly $300k

> Management of most top-level domains is delegated to responsible
>   organizations by the Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and
>   Numbers (ICANN), which operates the Internet Assigned Numbers
>   Authority (IANA) and is in charge of maintaining the DNS root zone.

http://www.icann.org/

http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/

http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could apply for your own gTLD, it will cost you though. A couple of hundred thousand USD at least.

Read more: http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/